# create a webform node with multi lingual language

Tags: nodes, webforms, uri, i18n-l10n

How to create a webform node with multi lingual language like french,spanish in drupal 6. so that when i hit the url it should display in particular language? webform localization is not supporting in drupal6. is there any other way around to do this. pls help?

Comment: both are raised by me. since i haven't get any answers i raised a separate one.

Comment: There is no need of raise a question again if you do not get a answer. You should wait for sometime to get answer.

Comment: so do you have any ideas for this issue ...am struggling with this !

Comment: Are you using `i18n` module?

Comment: No am not using i18n module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Internationalization](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) module to achieve this functionality.

> This is a collection of modules to extend Drupal core multilingual
>   capabilities and be able to build real life multilingual sites. Some
>   features:
>
> - Taxonomy translation (both, per language terms and translatable    terms) Multilingual variables
> - Multilingual blocks (control visibility per language and translate    title and content)
> - Language selection (when you switch the site language you'll see only    the content for that language)

Edit:

You need to set up *translate* of each node. If you create `node/2` as defualt language *French*, then you edit the node and click on *translate* tab in top of page and set up translate node in *spanish* language.

If you view `node/2` and select *spanish* language, then it will display the trasnlated node of `node/2` in *spanish* language.

Setting language:

- Go to the Languages page (`Administration > Settings > Language` in
  Drupal 6, or `Administration > Configuration > Regional and language >
  Languages` in Drupal 7) and add and enable desired languages.

Setting Multilingual for content type.

- Go to the Content types administration page (`Administration >
  Content > Types` in Drupal 6, or `Administration > Structure > Content
  types` in Drupal 7).
- Select a *content type* you want translated, and select "edit", then
  "Workflow settings" for Drupal 6 or "Publishing options" for Drupal
- At the "Multilingual support" section, select "Enabled, with
  translation". Be sure to save each content type after enabling
  multilingual support.

Comment: so if i create a new node like /node2 or /node3 and if i set up node2 default language is french and node3 default language is spanish. will that work..?

Comment: @user24393, I have updated my answer.

Comment: really sorry to bothering you while editing the node/2 by clicking the translate tab there i couldnt able to see specified setup to translate a node. pls help. instead i can see the below "Select translations for Support Request Form" text and a text field for english

Comment: @user24393, I have updated answer. I hope, it will solve your problem. As I did not have Drupal 6 site, so could not update properly.

Comment: @user24393, Refer https://drupal.org/node/1498708 for more information.

Comment: thanks for your all help. should i have to import french .po file to get the strings translated? or can i add manually into that for each form field i have created for node/2

Comment: @user24393, I have never worked on import `po` file. But you can use `string override` module if you want to form title string. Body and title of node, you need to manually translate the content.

Comment: these are great solutions but i'm still not getting my answers. May be have done something wrong. ill accept this as answer. thanks

Comment: @user24393, If you have still any question, you can ask.

Comment: wat i did is 1) i created two nodes one for french (node/2) and another one spanish(node/3) 2) i have included i18n module and selected all options.3) i have set up all the settings which u mentioned like a)Setting language and b)Setting Multilingual for content type as you mentioned. but still not getting node translated. i have a default node node/1 which is for english . Am i missing anything. am a newbie to this drupal . it might be annoying for u ;)

Comment: @user24393, I hope, when you edit node, you found `translate` tab. There is also a block `language switcher` in block list which you can render in page.

Comment: @user24393, For more information https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/translation

Comment: After some work around i can able to display the translated node today. however when im submitting the contact form , the entered details not getting displayed in webform-confirmation.tpl.php . The entered details are in webform-submissions table. The form (/node/2) just get submits. pls help

Comment: @user24393, I would like to help you but if you have any question for webform submission, so you should ask this separately.

Comment: created a new one.http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98314/webform-submission-details-not-getting-displayed