# webform submission details not getting displayed

Tags: nodes

i have multiple nodes each per language and the default is English(node/1). 
For french node(node/2) after submitting the details of the contact form, the details not getting displayed in Webform-Confirmation.tpl.php page, however when i do the same in default English node, it is getting displayed. any configuration should i do for this please help

Comment: Have you overridden template `webform-confirmation.tpl.php` for `node/2`?

Comment: yes made it as webform-confirmation.tpl.2.php still not worked

Comment: It should be `webform-confirmation-[nid].tpl.php` and you have to create template for other node.

Comment: how to create that template for new node.is there any work around, as am very new to drupal am struggling with this

Comment: Copy file from webform module and rename file as `webform-confirmation-[nid].tpl.php` and you should replace `[nid]` with your node id and clear cache.

Comment: i created a new webform-confirmation-2.tpl.php and cleared cache. still not getting the confirmation page

Comment: Edit your webform and check _Redirection location_ in your _form settings_ tab of the webform. It should be _Confirmation page_ checked.

Comment: I have added this as answer so it will help future user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set *Redirection location* of `webform` in form settings.

- Edit your `webform` node.
- Click on *webform* tab in top of page and it will redirect you to webform configuration of the node.
- Click on *form settings* link in webform
- Checked *Confirmation page* radios in *Redirection location* field-set and save the form.

[image: webform submission]